# How to change hint text color of a text field for mobile web in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

When I am trying to execute my titanium classic project(in mobile web preview in browser), hint text of textfield will not be gray, which makes no difference between normal text and hint text. can any one please guide me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not out of the box, anyway.
But there are other things you can try:

- Create  a label and set it to your hint label text and pick a color you desire.
- Next, place the label "on top" of your input, and listen for 'click' events, whenever there is a click you will need to hide the label and set focus to the input.
- After the input is done, you can listen to the 'blur' event to show the customized hint label again.

And there you have it, your own hint label.. I did this because I needed smaller fonts for the hint text.

Hope it helps,
-Lucas